# What is the difference between the following?

Tags: c++, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Assuming `A` is a class properly defined with constructors etc., what is the difference between these?

```
A *ptrA = new A;
A *ptrA = new A();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of `A` - "a class properly defined with constructors etc" is very unhelpful and impressively vague.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same

Comment: Most of the time, yes, but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new